# Create mapping code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Ok this is driving me insane.
I have tried to build a few tables using Code First but I cannot get it to do what I have asked.
So I have used SQL Management studio to create my tables which I will post now:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and for the product detail I have

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductDetail](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Summary] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductDetail]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductDetail_Products] FOREIGN KEY([ProductId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductDetail] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductDetail_Products]
GO
```

As you can see, if I delete a **Product** then the **ProductDetails** will also be deleted.
But if I delete my **ProductDetails** it does not cascade.

For some reason I am having great difficulty in replicating that in Code First EF.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: See this: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s04.html

Answer (score 0):

I've always generate my code first domain classes and mappings using [Entity Framework Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) and it works great. I've used this tool to generate code first classes on the base of your two tables, posted above. Here they are:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.ProductDetails = new List<ProductDetail>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(10);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Products");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
    }
}

public partial class ProductDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDetailMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductDetail>
{
    public ProductDetailMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(10);

        this.Property(t => t.Summary)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(10);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("ProductDetail");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        this.Property(t => t.Summary).HasColumnName("Summary");
        this.Property(t => t.ProductId).HasColumnName("ProductId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Product)
            .WithMany(t => t.ProductDetails)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProductId);

    }
}
```